# $f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$ for continuous function between two topological space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau')$ be two topological space. $$f:X\rightarrow Y \text{ is a continuous function implies for all } A\subseteq X, \\f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$$
> where $\bar{A} = A \cup A'$ is the closure of A.

*Note:-I know there are might be duplicates lying around MSE for this particular question. Even in the [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AR6sPMz3GKY&list=PLGr2lFX0u1-__lRhZ5SbOVIZZ5E7aouNu&index=5)  I'm following, there the professor has his own proof but my main reason for posting this is to verify the proof that I've written down.*

My attempt:
Let $y \in V \subset f(\bar{A})$, for arbitary open set $V$ in $\tau'$.
$\implies f^{-1}(y)\subseteq f^{-1}(V) \subseteq \bar{A}$.
Say $x\in f^{-1}(y)$, so  $f^{-1}(V)$ is a open neighbourhood for $x$.So by closure of A
$\implies f^{-1}(V)\cap A \neq \emptyset$
$\implies V\cap f(A) \neq \emptyset$
$\implies y \in \overline{f(A)}$
$\therefore f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$.
Proved.

Is my proof correct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is wrong. There need not be any such $V$. For a proof see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346971/problem-iii-2-7-in-textbook-analysis-i-by-amann-f-x-to-y-is-continuous-i?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there are some mistakes.  To prove that $f(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$, you should start by taking an arbitrary $y \in f(\overline{A})$ and then prove that $y \in \overline{f(A)}$.  To prove that $y \in \overline{f(A)}$, you should then take an arbitrary neighborhood $V$ of $y$.  You have combined these two steps into your first step; it would have been clearer to make it two separate steps.  But you have also added something in that step: you assumed that $V \subset f(\overline{A})$.  You shouldn't be making that assumption; $V$ needs to be an arbitrary neighborhood of $y$, so you can't make any further assumptions about it.  Fortunately, you never actually used your assumption that $V \subset f(\overline{A})$.

I would also have introduced $x$ differently.  I would have said: since $y \in f(\overline{A})$, we can choose some $x \in \overline{A}$ such that $f(x) = y$.  Since $y \in V$, it follows that $x \in f^{-1}(V)$.

Finally, your phrase "by closure of $A$" is unclear.  I think you mean "since $x \in \overline{A}$."

One bit of proof-writing advice:  I suggest that you stop using the symbol "$\Longrightarrow$" in your proofs.  Use English to say what you mean.